# Column does not exist foreign key table in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

In django, I created a new model in my application (The app name is quiz) like this:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    person1 = models.ForeignKey(Personality, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="person1", blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    person2 = models.ForeignKey(Personality, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="person2", blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    score = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

I then proceeded to do makemigrations and migrate, which was successful.
I also registered this model with the admin. But whenever I try to open it's page on the admin site, I get this message:

[image: Screenshot]

P.S. I'm using PostgreSQL as my backend

**EDIT**: Adding the output of the migration here:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.7 on 2021-06-01 13:40

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Personality',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('social', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('clean', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('organ', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('finance', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('opinion', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('people', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('cook', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('pet', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('night', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('spont', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('space', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('work', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('ambition', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('transport', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('chores', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('help', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Score',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('score', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0, max_digits=5)),
                ('person1', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, default=0, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='person1', to='quiz.personality')),
                ('person2', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, default=0, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='person2', to='quiz.personality')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the output of the makemigrations and migrate commands?

Comment: @MarcCompte added the output of the migration to the question

Comment: Hmm, I'm intrigued, it does look OK. And when running the migrate command you did see it executing this migration, right? Do you use only one DATABASE in your settings, or do you have more than one?

Comment: Yep it was this migration only. And no there is no other database I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with postgreSQL itself. Resolved the issue by following these steps:

1. Dropped the score and personality table from PostgreSQL.
2. Cleared the rows from the django_migrations table in PostgreSQL which were for the 'quiz' apps.
3. Cleared the migrations from the quiz app in django (leaving the init files)
4. Ran the makemigration and migrate commands again